# How can I uninstall python 2.6.5 and install the newest version(2.7.3) in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to uninstall python `2.6.5`, and install python `2.7.3`
but there is so many other software relay on it.

so how can I up upgrade python in `ubuntu10.04`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/10/10/installing-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) link to do the same(i.e the installation part), after doing this the default python version will change to `2.7.3`.

Another useful link [How do I install python 2.7.2 on 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-10-04).

Comment: I get an error: /usr/bin/install: cannot create directory `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig': File exists

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to uninstall the old one? You can install python 2.7 and just create a virtualenv that points to it: [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)
Aside from that, it's rather risky to upgrade it, if you don't want to upgrade the whole system.