# No module named requests after migrating from python 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, migration, python-requests, ubuntu-10.04

After I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120521/how-can-i-uninstall-python-2-6-5-and-install-the-newest-version2-7-3-in-ubuntu) procedure, I have problems with

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

When I

```
root@ubuntu:~# python -V
Python 2.7.8
```

And when I

```
root@ubuntu:~# pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

So it seems that I have `requests` installed but for python 2.6

EDIT, my system is Ubuntu 10.4 and previously I've installed `requests` via `pip`

I have:

```
root@ubuntu:~# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
root@ubuntu:~# which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
```

Comment: What is the output of `which python` and `which easy_install`?

Comment: @Salem question updated

Comment: How about removing it and re-installing it? 
sudo apt-get remove requests
and then 
sudo apt-get install requests.

I know the name of the package may be different.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Do you have any file named either `pip` or `easy_install` in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @Salem yes I have pip

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `pip` command you are using is "linked" to python2.6 version and not the one you want to use. You can try some things:

First of all check if you have any of `pip2.7`, `pip-2.7` or `easy_install-2.7` installed. If so you can use them to install your package:

```
pip-2.7 install requests # or easy_install-2.7 requests
```

If you don't have any of them try to run pip using your python version:

```
python /usr/local/bin/pip install requests
```

If this fails then I think the only way is to install `pip` manually. Before you do so, backup your system (usually python is used in many desktop and even cli apps in Ubuntu, so if you break it you may get a lot of problems).

- First install setuptools: this will make available `easy_install`

  ```
  wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
  ```
- After this, you can install the package you need or if you will need pip in the future, install `pip` and use it from here

  ```
  easy_install pip
  pip install requests
  ```